Patterns of inflection for Italian natives in natural conversations and whether they're common in other languages
When speaking with Italian natives in both English and Italian, I've noticed that they tend to place a considerable amount of stress on every other word in a sentence (barring words like oh, ah, etc. or even dummy pronouns such as there in sentences such as "there are tables in the distance"). Is this pattern the same in other languages like Spanish and French or even more "distant" languages like Slavic languages?

It is not accurate to say that in English we place stress on every other word. In English, each word that is stressed in a sentence by a speaker can change its meaning. Try saying these: He was a major player. [no particular stress]  He was a major player. He was a major player. He was a major player. He was a major player. He was a major player. Now, I don't speak Italian fluently, but what you say sounds wrong for that too. And these are called stress and intonation patterns. There is word stress and stress (intonation) over an utterance.

I'm not saying that it's usually done in English, it's usually done when an Italian native is speaking English. There are obviously exceptions when stress is needed on a specific word but the pattern follows in the same way from that point on as far as I've noticed (maybe another exception I should've added above)

When Italians are speaking English? OK. They are usually just keeping Italian intonation patterns in English. The stress on every other word though sounds wrong to me both for Italian and English.

I know, there's obviously exceptions I'll have missed as I did before, but for the most part, as weird as it seemed to me when I was picking up on it, the pattern does exist. It may be a regional thing since there's a lot of different dialects in Italy, but if you hear an Italian person talking naturally you might be able to hear it

Paolo, both Italian and English use pitch accent to convey meaning over the entire utterance. Italian is stronger but it also exists in English. This article will get you started: https://www.studiesaggilinguistici.it/ssl/article/view/99/76
